# Evaluating $E(x^{-1}). $

Tags: self-study, expected-value, moment-generating-function

Could you please help me to prove the following equation:

$$E(x^{-1})=\int_{0}^{\infty}M_{x}(-t)dt$$

Where $M_{x}(-t)$ is the moment-generating function.
I think the following equation will be useful:
$$x^{-1}=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{ux}du$$
for $x>0$

Comment: If this question is for homework, please note that.  If it is for self-study, please tag it as self-study and let us know where you got the question from.

Comment: I think applying a *definition* of the mgf would be the most useful way to start.  But aren't you making some strong assumptions about the distribution of $x$? For instance, suppose $x$ is a constant random variable almost surely equal to $-1,$ so that $M_x(t)=E[e^{tx}] = e^{-t}.$ The integral of $M_x(-t)=e^t$ diverges, but $E[x^{-1}]=1.$

Comment: "You think" doesn't mean what you listed is correct.  Please consider other's comments and suggestions seriously before making the claim, or even accepted a wrong answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}{e^{ux}du}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ux}du}$$

$$E\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-1}f\left(x\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ux}du}\right)f\left(x\right)dx=}}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ux}f(x)dx}\right)du\ =\int_{0}^{\infty}{M_X(-u)du\ =\ \int_{0}^{\infty}{M_X(-t)dt}}\ }$$

Comment: The first line should not begin with "E()."  The second line is valid only when $x$ has non-negative support, which is not a condition included in your question.